# Is there a way to resolve class method dynamically on Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, class, dynamic, methods, resolution

I can define and resolve dynamic method without any errors or warnings with `@property`, `@dynamic` and `-resolveInstanceMethod:`
However, they're instance methods, but I want to resolve class method dynamically. How can I archive this?

Comment: I've checked the method but it will cause some warning like "Method xxx not found" (LLVM). Is there a way to suppress this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`resolveClassMethod`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/resolveClassMethod:).

Nuff said.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection, follow this link: http://www.g8production.com/post/11140358039/objective-c-repleace-resolveclassmethod-and

Answer (score 0):

For those who worried about warning "Method definition not found", here is how to fix it:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wincomplete-implementation"

@implementation PBCodingCaseInt
......
@end
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```